# C macro to transform a SVN revision to an integer

Tags: c++, c, svn, macros, c-preprocessor

I am looking for a C/C++ macro that can transform a random SVN revision like "$Revision: 9 $" or "$Revision: 9999999 $" into an integer or a string.

I know that simple functions exists to achieve this, but I want this to be made at compile time.

My wish is to write things like:`unsigned int rev = SVN_TO_INT("$Revision$");`

Comment: The nice thing with compilers is that they can actually replace a function call with the resulting value if you use only compile-time constants. VC did that to me once when I wanted to compare a few ways of swapping values; the resulting assembler code (with /O2) didn't contain any function calls at all anymore; only constants.

Comment: If you want to automatically embed the revision number in the executable I think you are on the wrong path, since the revision number embeded through svn keywords changes only when commiting a *modified file*. Thus you can't be sure the file with the SVN_TO_INT macro will always reflect your project's revision.

Comment: I agree with your comment, however, the revision-per-file system is suitable for my use (one class per file and one revision per class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it is not doable with macros, however, I found a trick using compiler optimizations.
The result is that the expression JL_SvnRevToInt("$Revision: 12345 $") is reduced to a single unsigned integer: 12345

```
inline unsigned int JL_SvnRevToInt(const char *r) {


    if ( r == NULL || r[0] == '\0' || r[10] == '\0' || r[11] == '\0' || r[12] == '\0' || r[13] == '\0' )
    return 0;

    const unsigned int count = 
          r[11] == ' ' ? 1
        : r[12] == ' ' ? 10
        : r[13] == ' ' ? 100
        : r[14] == ' ' ? 1000
        : r[15] == ' ' ? 10000
        : r[16] == ' ' ? 100000
        : r[17] == ' ' ? 1000000
        : r[18] == ' ' ? 10000000
        : r[19] == ' ' ? 100000000
        : 0;

    return
        (r[11] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[11]-'0') * (count/10) +
        (r[12] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[12]-'0') * (count/100) + 
        (r[13] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[13]-'0') * (count/1000) + 
        (r[14] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[14]-'0') * (count/10000) + 
        (r[15] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[15]-'0') * (count/100000) +
        (r[16] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[16]-'0') * (count/1000000) +
        (r[17] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[17]-'0') * (count/10000000) +
        (r[18] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[18]-'0') * (count/100000000) +
        (r[19] == ' ' ? 0 : (r[19]-'0') * (count/1000000000) +
        0)))))))));
}
```

It supports9 digits revision number, NULL and empty and "$Revision$" strings.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that you can't work with strings at compile time through macros or templates.  So.... don't use strings.

This is an ugly hack, but I think it meets all your requirements.  I don't recommend it.

```
#define $Revision struct REV_STR { unsigned foo
#define $ * 64; };

$Revision: 4521 $

enum { REV = sizeof(REV_STR) / 8 };

#undef $Revision
#undef $

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout << REV << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

// $ g++ -Wall -Wextra revision.cpp && ./a.exe
// revision.cpp:4: warning: width of `REV_STR::foo' exceeds its type
// 4521
```

Comment: That's beautifully disgusting, and I salute you for it!

Comment: Respect!
I love it! 
Although i would recommend anyone against writing anything like it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm relatively sure that this isn't possible with a macro.

It may be possible with template metaprogramming, but I've never gone near it.

It would also be possible with a pre-build script that replaces SVN_TO_INT with your desired text.

I don't understand why you want this, though, since it would be just as easy to hardcode the version number since you know it at compile time.

Comment: Yeah but it's a pain to change it every time :)

Comment: You can actually hack together a script which will run in the makefile or so and put a -DSVN_REVISION=89278 into the command line.

Comment: +1 for basically "why if you can do it before compilation" which i was to preoccupied to think of.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do the kind of string manipulation you want at compile time with the C preprocessor (macros) or with templates (C++).  You'll need to use an external utility or script that you can invoke from the build process.

Some utilities/scripts/code that might help you:

- SvnRev: http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm
- http://blog.guymahieu.com/2008/06/09/getting-the-svn-head-revision-number-from-a-windows-batch-file/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/svn_visual_studio.aspx

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
#define $Revision (false?1
#define $ +0)

int codeRevision() { return $Revision: $; }

#undef $Revision
#undef $
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't fully work with strings at preprocessing or compile time - but why not use something something like:

```
int svn_version() 
{
     static const int v = extract_svn_version(REVISION);
     return v;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid the revision string to be stored in my binary file ("$Revision: XXXX $")

Comment: Then you have to do it outside of your source and define it in the build enviroment - even though in C++0x there seems to be compile time string processing (before that there is none) i guess that still doesn't guarantee that the string literal will be eliminated from the binary - the compiler may or may not do that.

Comment: Why don't you want it in your binary file?  What we used to use that for (in CVS) was so we could find the build information on a binary.  Once the binaries went to the customers, we had no control over where they went, and it was sometimes real useful to know which version a certain customer system was running.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `makefile` based build system you can make a special rule that creates a file every `make`time.

```
.PHONY: svn_revision.c

svn_revision.c:
        echo -n "int svn_revision = " > svn_revision.c
        svn info | grep Revision | cut -f2 -d" " >> svn_revision.c
        echo ";"  >> svn_revision.c

svn_revision.o: svn_revision.c
```